# Solr - Sort results by order of value in query

Tags: solr

I am working with Solr and I have a issue. It is:
I use query to get results in Solr and the results are not my expectation. The query is : product_id: ("2" OR "3" OR "1") and the order of results do not like the order I input in query. maybe it's 1-2-3 or 3-2-1. The order of results I expect is as same order as I query 2-3-1.

So are there solution to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, boost each term with a differnt, decreasing value, for example:

```
q=product_id:2^10 3^5 1
```

Look the specifics on the [docs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/the-standard-query-parser.html#boosting-a-term-with)